# Need help to update record with foreach loop in SSIS

Tags: stored-procedures, ssis, store, foreach-loop-container

I'm working on data cleansing project where I'm executing 1st stored procedure to get all the data which has issue and store it into a staging table1 with ID, IND_REF, CODE.

Table structure is:

```
ID | IND_REF|CODE
12 |  2333  |ABC
13 |  1222  |EFG
```

Now each code associated with IND_ref  is primary key of the table2 and email table where data will be updated.

Next I wrote another stored procedure with an `IF` statement stating,

- If code = ABC then update school email as main email where emailtable_ID = staging table IND_REF

Once it update all the row of email table by reference of staging table IND_REF I used another if statement,

- IF code = 'EFG' do that.... where table2_ID = staging table IND_REF...

and so on..

Basically I want to update the row of live table by referencing CODE associated with each IND_REF...

Can I achieve this with a SSIS package? Can I loop through the staging table to update the live table? Any help would be much appreciated. I am new to the SQL world so I find it difficult to loop through each record by setting counter to update live table. any help with script would be very helpful.

Comment: Why would you alter the table? You're not changing columns. All you need is _one_ update statement to do all of that. You don't need a cursor or loop

Comment: Thanks a lot nick. My only concern is i have capture the account ID of all the issue record and stored each issue with a Code. For example ID 123,444,333,22,11,1111, all  has incorrect organization name which is saved in my staging table under the code 'ILOL' . now in update statement i referred  if code=ILOL then update org table  where ID=staging table ind_ref. how can i make this update by looping around the staging table through a ssis package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your issue but let me show you an example:

If we have a table like this:

```
TABLE1
ID    ind_ref    code
1        1        ABC
2       15        DEF
3       17        GHI
```

and a table like this:

```
TABLE2
ind_ref2  code
1         ZZZ
2         XXX
3         DDD
4         ZZZ
5         XXX
15        FFF
17        GGG
```

Then if we run this query:

```
UPDATE TABLE2
SET Code = TABLE1.Code
FROM TABLE1
WHERE TABLE1.ind_ref = TABLE2.ind_ref2;
```

Table 2 will end up like this:

```
TABLE2
ind_ref2  code
1         ABC    <= I got updated
2         XXX
3         DDD
4         ZZZ
5         XXX
15        DEF    <= me too
17        GHI    <= and me
```

If this is not your data or your requirement, please take the time to lay out examples as I have: explain the data that you have and what you want it to look like.

Note: SSIS is not required here and neither is looping.

Comment: Hi Nick thanks for your answer, you almost got me.. i will get back to you with proper explanation

Comment: I have update my question. hope it will help you to understand what i'm trying to achieve Nick. Thanks alot..

Comment: Unless you add sample data like I have, your problem is opaque to me. Can you at least clarify: how many tables are you updating? Just one table or many different tables?

Comment: Can you add the 'ILOL' thing that you mentioned in your comments to the sample data in your question.

Comment: Hi Nick I will update 6 different table , ind_ref is the primary key to all the table . Based on that I'm going to update all 6 table ..

Comment: And the value "ILOL" decides it goes to one table. A different value decides it will go to a different table - is that correct? What is the field called that contains "ILOL"?

Comment: No not the value "ILOL" but the update statement i will mentioned in my 2nd store procedure where i will use IF code ="ILOL" . lets break it down. The code "ILOL" is going to be mentioned in my second store procedure in If statement        eg  IF  code = "ILOL" then make update in column2 as "abcd...". in all the row of table2  by referring the IND_REF associated with the code "ILOL" in table 1 where the IND_REF table1=IND_REF table 2

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. If you would just post sample data instead of trying to explain in words I might.

Comment: Hi Nick, Finally i was able to get what i wanted . I achieved it through ssis using oledb command  in dataflow. Thanks for trying to helping me out brother.. much appreciated.